# ListView Row Height Question

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I am working with a WinForms application and I need to programatically determine the height of a ListView row.

I am able to determine the height of the text using `Graphics.MeasureString`, but there's some padding above and below the text.

I am not customizing each row, I just need the height.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer.

```
if (lv.Items.Count > 0)  
{  
    Rectangle r = lvMain.Items[0].Bounds;  
    String rowFormat = String.Format("Height: {0}", r.Height);  
    MessageBox.Show(rowFormat, "Alert!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);  
}
```